# Counters inside a function

Tags: ruby, counter

I'm trying to get a some counters inside a function that gets called repeatly.

In the function, `gets` is passed a value between 1 and 6 and then inside the function are a bunch of `if` statements. Inside the `if` statements I want to put a counter so I know how times each part of the `if` statement is true.

I've tried `x = x+1` inside the `if` but it doesn't like that:

```
 def check(number)
    if number == 1
       x = x+1
       if x == 3
         return true
       end
    elsif number == 2
      y = y+1
    elsif number == 3
      z = z + 1
    end
end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: sorry, thought i had

Comment: What are `x`, `y` and `z` in this context? They're not declared or initialized here.

Comment: how do you initialize?

Comment: This looks more like something that should be "solved" with an array or hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you're using here is a clunky way of doing this:

```
def check(number)
  case (number)
  when 1
    @x += 1

    true
  when 2
    @y += 1
  when 3
    @z += 1
  end
 end
```

Remember that in Ruby the last statement to evaluate is the one that's returned by default, so there's no need to be explicit about the `return` unless there's additional code after that point. In this case there isn't.

Secondly, unless you have `attr_accessors`, then `x = x + 1` isn't going to do anything useful. That will declare a local, initially `nil`, and then try and add 1 to it, an invalid operation. Presumably you mean to have `@x` initialized to 0 elsewhere and then track it in here.

Comment: When i do it that way i get "undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)" come up. do i need to declare x,y,z outside the function?

Comment: I'm presuming `@x`, `@y` and `@z` are set to 0 in your `initialize` method for whatever class contains this.

Comment: "Secondly, unless you have attr_accessors, then `x = x + 1` isn't going to do anything useful." FYI, even with an attr_accessor that statement won't do anything useful. Setter methods need to be called with `self.attr = ...`, without `self`, `attr = ...` always sets a local variable.

Comment: @Ajedi32 That's a great point. I usually prefix by `self.` out of habit to be explicit so I'd forgotten about this.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables don't retain their values across different invocations of a method, that would be very weird.

If the counter values are semantically a property of the method itself, I would use a closure:

```
x = y = z = 0
define_method(:check) do |number|
  case number
  when 1 then x += 1; return true if x == 3
  when 2 then y += 1
  when 3 then z += 1
  end
end
```

Alternatively, if the counter values are semantically a property of the object, I would use private getters and setters:

```
def check(number)
  case number
  when 1 then self.x += 1; return true if x == 3
  when 2 then self.y += 1
  when 3 then self.z += 1
  end
end

private

attr_accessor :x, :y, :z

def initialize
  self.x = self.y = self.z = 0
end
```